# Is it possible to use try with resources on java 5?

Tags: java-5, try-with-resources

I'm working on a project which has the constraint of using java 1.5.
My problem is that it is full of boilerplate like this:

```
Query q = null;
   try {
    q = getTemplatedQuery("updateConfigurationSyncTimestamps").prepareQuery(false);
    q.addParameter("id", copyConfiguration.getId())
        .addParameter("targetLastSyncTime", targetSyncTime)
        .addParameter("targetLastSuccessfullSyncTime", lastSyncErrors == 0 ? targetSyncTime : null)
        .addParameter("lastSyncErrors", lastSyncErrors);
    q.executeUpdate();
   } finally {
    if (q != null) {
     q.closeStatement();
    }
   }
```

How can I solve this problem in java 1.5? What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to use a construct like the try-with-resources in java 1.7 or something similar. I just want to close a statement no matter what happens while the program is running but without the boilerplate in the example.

Comment: Use the same design as Spring's JdbcTemplate: write a method that contains the boilerplate, and accepts a callback object defining the non-boilerplate part.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking about as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Apache Commons [IOUtils.closeQuietly()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#closeQuietly%28java.io.Closeable...%29) in your finally block to reduce it down to one line.